# Crack spanning several tiles

Tags: floor, tile, foundation, crack

I've got several tiles in my dining room that have a diagonal crack running across them. Since it's a pretty straight line across several tiles, I'm guessing it's a foundation issue. The room is at the corner of the house, and the crack runs diagonally so that it "cuts off" the corner. If I replace the tiles, is it likely to crack again? Is there any way I can remedy this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how old your house is.  If it's at least 5-10 years old or so, it's probably finished settling and installing new tiles would likely fix the problem permanently.

Comment: The house is almost 8 years old.

Comment: @Doresoom - You should be good then.  Most settling happens in the first year anyways, so by 8 years it's probably settled as much as it's going to.